# fstream declaration exception after hardclosing console / c++

Tags: c++, console, fstream

I stumbled upon the following problem:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

class TestClass
{
public:
    ~TestClass();
};

TestClass::~TestClass()
{
    fstream f;
}

TestClass test;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Sleep(10000);
}
```

This is a simple example so that you can reproduce my error. Everything works fine until I close console window manually (by pressing X in the console corner) while Sleep.
Access Violation Exception is thrown at the

```
fstream f;
```

line in destructor. Is there any way to use fstream after manual console closing? Or i'm doing something totally wrong?

UPD:

Stack looks like this:

```
msvcp120d.dll!std::ctype<char>::widen(char _Byte) Line 2418

msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >::widen(char _Byte) Line 129

msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char> >::init(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> > * _Strbuf, bool _Isstd) Line 170

msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> > * _Strbuf, bool _Isstd) Line 48

msvcp120d.dll!std::basic_iostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::basic_iostream<char,std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> > * _Strbuf) Line 954

ConsoleApplication6.exe!std::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::basic_fstream<char,std::char_traits<char> >() Line 1133

ConsoleApplication6.exe!TestClass::~TestClass() Line 19
```

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @Medinoc, really nothing interesting:


msvcp120d.dll!0fc68174()

[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for msvcp120d.dll]


[External Code] 


> ConsoleApplication6.exe!TestClass::~TestClass() Line 20  

[External Code]

Comment: @Medinoc, updated post with a stack information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this stack trace, the problem is indeed from a call from fstream's constructor: `ios_base::init()` initializes some variable with `widen(' ')`, which calls `ctype::widen` on what is probably a null or destroyed `ctype` object (returned by `use_facet`), which causes a crash when it tries to call a virtual member function.

Conclusion: some vital objects in the CRT are destroyed before your `TestClass` object is, therefore you can't use CRT types in your global destructor.

Comment: Seems to be true. Is there any other way to use fstream after console closing?

Comment: Will mark this as correct answer until there will be something more useful